# Как правильно "из махагона" или "из махагони"?

Tags: склонение

В объявлении о продаже гитары увидел:

> Дека из махагон**и**

Однако до этого всегда считал правильным "из махагон**а**" по аналогии с "из клён**а**", "из дуб**а**".

Какой вариант верный?

Answer (score 1):

Слово **"махагон"** - это разговорный вариант, большинство словарей предлагает слово **"махагони"**. Например:

> махаго́ни, *нескл., с.*
>
> *Русское словесное ударение. — М.: ЭНАС. М.В. Зарва. 2001.*

**Обновление** (по комментарию @grizzly):

> МАХАГО́НИ *неизм.; ср.;* (разг.) МАХАГО́Н, -а; *м.* [от англ. mahogany]
>
> *Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт С. А. Кузнецов. 1998*

Comment: Толковый словарь Кузнецова отмечает также слово **махагон** в м.р., но помечает его как разговорное.